# ActivePython and MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, activepython

I have installed ActivePython and am trying to import MySQLdb

```
>> import mySQLdb
```

gives me an error stating `No module called MySQLdb`

I have tried searching but all the resources out there explain how to set up the mySQLdb for unix, not for windows, can you please tell me how I can do that with ActivePython? I am also planning to use pyDev (eclipse) from now on, how do I configure MySQLdb in both cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed HOWTO [over here](http://www.fuyun.org/2009/12/install-mysql-for-python-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

To install [MySQL-Python](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/mysql-python/),

```
pypm install mysql-python
```